# Add Character to Python regular exprsession

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following string:

`mystring='Main St and I295'`

I want it to instead be `'Main St and I-295'`. How can I add the dash to any string where I have a number directly followed by "I" with no spaces?

I can identify the pattern like this:

```
>>> re.findall('I\d+',mystring)
['I295']
>>>
```

But how can I add the dash to this pattern?

I tried `re.sub('I\d+', 'I-\d+',mystring)` but this gives me a string representation of my pattern.

Comment: `re.sub(r'I(\d+)', r'I-\1', mystring)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's time for you to learn about regex [capture groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)!

In your pattern, enclose the data you want to capture in (parens) like so:

```
>>> mystring = 'Main St and I295'
>>> pattern = r'I(\d+)'
>>> re.sub(pattern, 'I-\g<1>', mystring)
'Main St and I-295'
```